# How can I make sure that the means can be seen to form an approximate eq triangle, after generating 3 off 2D norm distr with 1000 points each

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I generate three 2D normally distributed distributions with 1000 points each with
different means and variances and made sure there is some overlap between the three
distributions by visualising the distributions.

```
dist1= 10 + 5 * np.random.randn(1000,1)
dist2= 15 + 20 * np.random.randn(1000,1)
dist3= 20 + 5 * np.random.randn(1000,1)
```

Also, the exercise is asking to make sure that the means can be seen to form an approximate equilateral triangle, so I have done this

```
plt.hist(dist1, bins="auto", stacked =True, alpha=0.3)
plt.axvline(dist1.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.hist(dist2, bins="auto", stacked =True, alpha=0.3)
plt.axvline(dist2.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.hist(dist3, bins="auto", stacked =True, alpha=0.3)
plt.axvline(dist3.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Would this be the right approach? I am not sure how to create 3 lines so that it shows a triangle

I have also tried this:

```
D1 = np.random.normal(1.1,5, 1000)
D2 = np.random.normal(1.05,4, 1000)
D3 = np.random.normal(1,3, 1000)

x=np.average(D1)
y=np.average(D2)
z=np.average(D3)

print('')

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(y,z)
plt.scatter(z,x)

plt.plot((x,y),(y,z),'-r')
plt.plot((y,z),(z,x),'-p')
plt.plot((z,x),(x,y),'y')

print('')
```

So I could see the triangle, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2D distribution, the arrays need to have a shape of `(N,2)`. A shape of `(N,1)` is only 1D. To form an equilateral triangle, the third center could be at `D*sqrt(3)/2` above the middle point of the two other centers (with `D` the distance between them). You could visualize the points via `plt.scatter(dist1[:,0], dist1[:,1])` (`dist1[:,0]` would be the x-coordinates, `dist1[:,1]` the y-coordinates).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dist1 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 5 + np.array([10, 10])
dist2 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 10 + np.array([30, 10])
dist3 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 7 + np.array([20, 10 + np.sqrt(400 / 3)])

plt.scatter(dist1[:, 0], dist1[:, 1], color='r', alpha=0.1, s=1)
plt.scatter(dist2[:, 0], dist2[:, 1], color='g', alpha=0.1, s=1)
plt.scatter(dist3[:, 0], dist3[:, 1], color='b', alpha=0.1, s=1)

center1 = dist1.mean(axis=0)
center2 = dist2.mean(axis=0)
center3 = dist3.mean(axis=0)
plt.plot([center1[0], center2[0], center3[0], center1[0]],
         [center1[1], center2[1], center3[1], center1[1]],
         lw=3, ls='--', color='gold')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3 2D normal distributions]

To concatenate the arrays, and assign a label to each part, you could use:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dist1 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 5 + np.array([10, 10])
dist2 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 10 + np.array([30, 10])
dist3 = np.random.randn(10000, 2) * 7 + np.array([20, 10 + np.sqrt(400 / 3)])
dist4 = np.concatenate([dist1, dist2, dist3])
class_label = np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [dist1.shape[0], dist2.shape[0], dist3.shape[0]])
plt.scatter(dist4[:, 0], dist4[:, 1], c=class_label, cmap='tab10', alpha=0.1, s=1)
plt.show()
```

You could also add the labels as a third dimension:

```py
dist4_with_label = np.hstack([dist4, class_label.reshape(-1, 1)])
plt.scatter(dist4_with_label[:, 0], dist4_with_label[:, 1], c=dist4_with_label[:, 2],
            cmap='tab10', alpha=0.1, s=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to concatenate the datasets so that I have a matrix with a shape of 3000 x 1 in size, do you think I should apply this: dist4=np.concatenate([dist1,dist2,dist3])? ..It resulted into a 2D array and the shape is dist4.shape -> (30000, 2). I will need then to increase the dimensionality of the data by adding a third dimension which is a class label, indicating which cluster that data point belongs to, i.e. 0,1 or 2.

Comment: for label=label, was is supposed to be label="label"? otherwise I get an error saying that label wasn't defined.

Comment: thank you. I have also updated my initial code and added another potential way of working on this exercise. would that be correct? when I ran it's shape it says its a 2D even though I defined one of the arrays as: D1 = np.random.normal(1.1,5, 1000)

Comment: I updated the plot with a triangle connecting the 3 centers.